# R kmeans data points

Tags: r, statistics, k-means, correspondence

I am using the following to perform a kmeans analysis:

```
km = kmeans(mat2, centers = 4)
```

I have also plotted the kmeans analysis using `library(fpc)` to get a visual as follows:

```
plotcluster(mat2, km$cluster)
```

Here is the result:[image]

Each row of `mat2` corresponds to a point in the plot. I gave each row in the matrix a name with the following:

```
rownames(mat2) = names      #names is a vector corresponding to the rows of mat2
```

I can find the membership of each row in the matrix by the following attribute:

```
km$cluster
```

This gives the name of each row in the matrix, followed by the corresponding integer in the plot. However, I would like to access more data.

**How do I access more data from these cluster points?** For example I would like to find the correspondence between integers in the plot and rows in the matrix. To clarify, answering this question would allow me to know which row in the matrix corresponds to the highest 2 in the plot? Once I know which integers correspond to which rows in the matrix, then I have the names of each  row in the matrix and can give a meaningful interpretation.

I would also like to find the distance measure between a point in the plot and the center of the cluster to which it belongs. Can I get a correspondence between (x, y) coordinates in the plot to the rows in the matrix? Can I get an interactive GUI so that when I click on a cluster point in the plot, I can see more some of the data described above? I am open to using a different library for plotting. Summarizing into two questions:

1. How can I get the correspondence between the integers in the plot and the rows in the matrix?
2. Is there an existing package or tool that would make this a lot easier for me?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are asking several discrete questions, such that a single answer will not be able to cover all. Consider refining?

Comment: The question at the bottom clarifies the main question.

Comment: What is the output from `str(mat2)`?

Comment: The dimensions of the matrix are 291 X 31. Then each row has a name.

Comment: "get the correspondence between the integers in the plot and the rows in the matrix" can be done using a technique called "brushing". I've used that technique in S-Plus to good effect, but not in R. (iPlots)[http://www.rosuda.org/iplots/iplots.html] is one graphing package for R that appears to include brushing as a feature -- as I say, I haven't used it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answering some of your question, but there is a lot in there. If you want to interact with your plot to identify points, you can look at `?identify`. Here's an answer to working with the specific rows you're after. If you want to ask about interactive GUIs perhaps post a specific question regarding that.

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(160), ncol=2)
km <- kmeans(mat, centers=4)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(mat, km$cluster))
names(df) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "cluster")

#Get the row of df with highest Var1 and cluster == 2
which(df$Var1 == max(df$Var1[df$cluster==2]))
# 76

#Use this to extract the row
df[which(df$Var1 == max(df$Var1[df$cluster==2])),]

#You can subset you data based on one of the variables
#Get the rows with cluster == 2
df.2 <- df[df$cluster == 2,]
```

Comment: I do not really want to find the row of the matrix of the point with the highest variance from a cluster, that was just an example to help clarify. I want to find the row of the matrix for any point.

Comment: So why aren't you checkmarking this when the answer you were seeking has been given???

Comment: Did not realize at first that this was the mapping that I was looking for!